# How to force a WebAPI OData expand clause?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

Using Microsoft WebAPI OData version 5.6 (OData v3), if I have the following custom model/DTOs:

```
public class ParentObject
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public ChildObject Child { get; set;}
}  

public class ChildObject
{
  public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

And the following controller that projects my database into the model:

```
public class ParentsController : ODataController
{
  public IQueryable<ParentObject> Get()
  {
    var db = new MyDBContext();
    var results = from p in db.parent
                  select new ParentObject
                  {
                    ID = p.id,
                    Title = p.title,
                    Child = p.child == null ? null : new ChildObject 
                    {
                      Value = p.child.value
                    }
                   };

    return results;
   }
  }
}
```

How can I force "Child" to be expanded without the consumer needing to specify $expand=Child in the url?

I want to:
1. Check to see if the consumer already specified the $expand=Child
2. If "Child" is not already included in the expand list, include it.
3. Be sure to respect any other query options

I have looked at several online articles that are either unclear to me or reference an older version of the api that no longer matches up.

I have tried modifying the Action to "Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)" which let's me do something like:

```
if(opts.SelectExpand == null || !opts.SelectExpand.RawExpand.Contains("Child"))
{
  // Add/modify expand clause here.
}
```

However I am not clear on how to either modify or build up my own ODataQueryOptions object, maintaining all of the other query options and then applying it to the results.

**Update 1**

I have made some progress. Here's the relevant changes to the controller (the dbcontext query is same as above):

```
public PageResult<ParentObject> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
{
 SelectExpandQueryOption expandOpts = null;
 if(opts.SelectExpand != null && !opts.SelectExpand.RawExpand.Contains("Child"))
 {
  expandOpts = new SelectExpandQueryOption(opts.SelectExpand.RawSelect, string.Join(",", new string[] {"Child", opts.SelectExpand.RawExpand }), opts.Context);
 }
 else if (opts.SelectExpand == null)
 {
  expandOpts = new SelectExpandQueryOption(null, "Child", opts.Context);
 }

 // Query from above goes here

 if(expandOpts != null)
 {
  Request.SetSelectExpandClause(expandOpts.SelectExpandClause);
 }

 var qSettings = new ODataQuerySettings();
 qSettings.PageSize = 100;

 results = opts.ApplyTo(results, qSettings).AsQueryable() as IQueryable<ParentObject>;
 return new PageResult<ParentObject>(results, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
}
```

This seems to work fine when I do not include a "$expand" query option (expandOpts is created). However, when "$expand" is present, I'm getting a ArgumentNullExcpetion on the return statement and can't figure out why.

Comment: Your technique worked for me too. You should put it as an answer and mark it as accepted. The only difference is that `Request.SetSelectExpandClause` is obsolete so I used `Request.ODataProperties().SelectExpandClause` property instead

Comment: From v7 you can add the `AutoExpand` attribute on the property.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours on this one myself this is the answer. You need to set the expand string AND do the include to get it working.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Student> Get_Student(ODataQueryOptions<Student> queryOptions)
{
var db = new EfCustomAdapter();

var  expandOpts = new SelectExpandQueryOption(null, "Parent,Schools", queryOptions.Context);
var q = db.Student.AsQueryable();
q = q.Include(t => t.Parent);
q = q.Include(t => t.Schools);
queryOptions.Request.ODataProperties().SelectExpandClause = expandOpts.SelectExpandClause;
return q;
}
```

Update:
If you need to expand levels below the syntax is..
"parents,schools,bills/payments"

the payments object being a navigation property of the bill.

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful!
I note though, if the $select odata query option is also used then this code would replace it?
I have tried pulling the $select option and passing as the first parameter of SelectExpandQueryOption() consrtructor.
This has weird side effects if the new expand option does not validate against the original select option.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look near the bottom of this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options. The MyQueryableAttribute may be what you need. You could create a custom `QueryableWithChildAttribute` class which injects the queryOptions.Expand you need. Then, just decorate your method with `[QueryableWithChild()]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although this wasn't the answer and I looked at this page 100 times, you somehow got me down the right path so I will accept this as the answer and update my post.

Comment: I thought I had this working but it's not quite working fully yet. Have to unaccept and will update question with progress. Sorry :(